# I can't update my packages in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: command-line, apt

I am trying to update the packages on my system but I get this errors:
[image: updateError]

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: The errors related to the EOL status.. The warnings notices were offered to users prior to EOL & posted online ~6 weeks prior to EOL (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/) but after EOL the repositories are *dropped* from mirrors and the main archive it moved as per EOLUpgrades link provided.

Answer (score 2):

Source: @guiverc

> Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this [site](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.
> [Upgrade Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades)

> The errors related to the EOL status... The warnings notices were offered to users prior to EOL(eg.[https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish...](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/)) & posted online ~6 weeks prior to EOL  but after EOL the repositories are dropped from mirrors and the main archive it moved as per EOLUpgrades link provided.
> [EOLUpgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)

Now do `sudo do-release-upgrade` to fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you, @RishonJR, for your answer if I run the command you provided, will it upgrade my system to Ubuntu 22 ?

Comment: yes, it will update to 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: No need to apologize... it was as much as ensuring the links were correct, and helping you learn the ways of sites like this..  (*we all start off & slowly learn*)

Comment: I am trying to find a way without upgrading because I am afraid of losing my data don't know where to get buck up, and also it might need to set up again some programs and i don't have time for that however thank you for the answer

Comment: While it is always a good idea to back up your data before an update, the `do-release-upgrade` process in itself does not delete the `/home` partition but keeps it intact.